# Clojure reify a Java interface with overloaded methods

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm trying to implement the following Java interface in Clojure:

```
package quickfix;

public interface MessageFactory {
    Message create(String beginString, String msgType);
    Group create(String beginString, String msgType, int correspondingFieldID);
}
```

The following Clojure code is my attempt at doing this:

```
(defn -create-message-factory 
  []
  (reify quickfix.MessageFactory
    (create [beginString msgType]
      nil)
    (create [beginString msgType correspondingFieldID]
      nil)))
```

This fails to compile with the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: create

The [documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify) suggests overloaded interface methods are ok, so long as the arity is different as it is in this case:

> If a method is overloaded in a protocol/interface, multiple
>   independent method definitions must be supplied. If overloaded with
>   same arity in an interface you must specify complete hints to
>   disambiguate - a missing hint implies Object.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing a parameter. The first parameter of every method implemented by `reify` is the object itself (as is the case with `defrecord`/`deftype`). So, try this:

```
(defn -create-message-factory 
  []
  (reify quickfix.MessageFactory
    (create [this beginString msgType]
      nil)
    (create [this beginString msgType correspondingFieldID]
      nil)))
```