# How to reify Java Interfaces with overloaded method?

Tags: clojure, reify

I am trying to 'implement' the following Java interface from JGroups with `reify`.

```java
public interface MessageListener extends StateListener {
   /**
    * Called when a message is received.
    * @param msg
    */
    void receive(Message msg);

    /** Called when a batch of messages is received */
    default void receive(MessageBatch batch) {
        for(Message msg: batch) {
            try {receive(msg);}
            catch(Throwable t) {}
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the receive method is present twice, with one parameter each (and different types, of course). When I try to `reify` with the following code in CIDER:

```clj
(reify org.jgroups.MessageListener (receive[#^org.jgroups.Message msg] 
                                     (println msg)))
```

I get an error message:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: receive, compiling:(*cider-repl clj-groups*:49:21)
```

As `receive` is definitely available in the interface, I assume that this issue is related to the overloaded method and my typ hint is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: After changing the code according to Lees comment:

```clj
(reify org.jgroups.MessageListener (receive[this #^org.jgroups.Message msg]                                     
                                     (println msg)))
```

the error message changed:

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched return type: receive, expected: void, had: java.lang.Object, compiling:(*cider-repl clj-groups*:80:21)
```

Comment: You at least need to add a `this` parameter: `(receive [this msg] ...)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000267/clojure-reify-a-java-interface-with-overloaded-methods

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure reify a Java interface with overloaded methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000267/clojure-reify-a-java-interface-with-overloaded-methods)

Comment: Difference between the possible duplicate and me is that the methods have the same parameter count and type hinting is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Lee. I updated the question

Comment: Try adding `^void` between `receive` and `[` to type hint the return value.  l don't know whether that will work.

Comment: Mars, Unfortunately, not. The error message does not change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works when you add missing `this` argument and hint the return and argument types:

```
$ boot -d org.jgroups/jgroups:4.0.0.Final repl

(import '(org.jgroups MessageListener Message) '(org.jgroups.util MessageBatch))
;;=> org.jgroups.util.MessageBatch

(def listener
  (reify MessageListener
    (^void receive [this ^Message msg] (println "Message"))
    (^void receive [this ^MessageBatch batch] (println "MessageBatch"))))
;;=> #'boot.user/listener

(.receive listener (Message.))
;; Message
;;=> nil

(.receive listener (MessageBatch. 0))
;; MessageBatch
;;=> nil
```

Comment: From the doc on reify: "If you supply any hints at all, no inference is done, so all hints (or default of Object) must be correct, for both arguments and return type."